# Whats the easiest way to programmatically establish VPN connection? (pptp) Is it using .aidl files?

Tags: android, vpn

I'm trying to establish VPN connection using PPTP, I would like to make it as simple as possible (user friendly). 
I searched a lot tried few things with no luck, and got across method that use AIDL, I'm not 100% sure, but I think that thanks to that I would be able to use hidden android method (for example `PptpProfile` `IVpnServices.aidl` `VpnProfile.aidl` etc). I wonder: am I going the right way? If not could you give me advice what's the better way to establish pptp connection?

But on the other hand if I'm going "right way", I got a problem. I have copied `IVpnServices.aidl` and `VpnProfile.aidl` to my project, `IVpnServices.java` is generated, but with error:

> android.net.vpn.VpnProfile cannot be resolved to a type

According to AIDL tutorial, I should also copy `VpnProfile.java` to my project, but it refers to many other classes, that are also hidden, and cause more errors...
Does anyone know how to solve/get around it? I would be grateful for any advice.